# Insert/Inject an Object to string code

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, codedom, csharpcodeprovider

I have a C# code generated dynamically using `System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit` in runtime, I compile it using `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` , What I want is to insert an already defined & initialized Variable (an ArrayList) to this string so I could use it before compile, How should I do this?

Comment: You do know that `ArrrayList` is obsolete, right?

Comment: No , I didn't , Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: It's been obsolete for ten years! Use `List<T>` instead. Use `List<object>` if you really need a collection which can hold every kind of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate the code which creates this variable and fills it with the values you have. Or you can add an argument for one of the methods you generate and pass it at runtime. There's no magic method which will do it fo you.

CodeDom is incomplete, obsolete and outdated. Nowadays you should use T4 (if you want code as text) or Expressions and IL (if you want to execute dynamically generated code). If you use Expessions, inserting a variable is trivial. With T4, it'll take just a couple of lines of code, but will require doing it manually too.